# If $ f(x) + x^4[f(x)]^3 = 12$ and $f(2) = 2$, find $f′(2)$.

Tags: calculus

I am lost on this problem can someone help me out please?

Comment: Try implicit differentiation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x) + 4x^3(f(x))^3 + x^4(3f(x)^2)f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow f'(2) + 4\cdot 2^3\cdot (f(2))^3 + 2^4\cdot 3\cdot (f(2))^2\cdot f'(2) = 0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: This is the right general idea, but misses the key issue. See Abel's answer.

Comment: not verifying  $f(2) \neq 2$ has nothing to do with the level of the OP. you are perpetuating the nonsense that you can implicitly differentiate without any concern for what is being done.

Answer (score 2):

you have $$y + x^4y^3 = 12 \tag 1$$ but then at $x = 2, y = 2,$ the left hand side evaluates to $2+2^4 2^3 = 130$ which does match the right hand side $12.$ so check your initial values $x$ and $y.$

you can implicitly difference the constraint $(1)$ like this

$$0 = dy + x^4\, dy^3 + y^3 \, dx^4 = dy + 3x^4y^2\, dy+4y^3x^3\, dx \tag 2$$
sub your initial values that are consistent with the constraint $(1)$ into $(2)$ to find the slope of the tangent line $\frac{dy}{dx}.$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) + x^4[f(x)]^3 = 12$ and $f(2)=2$

$\frac{d}{dx}[f(x) + x^4[f(x)]^3 = 12] \; \; \Rightarrow \;\;$ $f'(x) + 4x^3 \cdot [f(x)]^3 + x^4 \cdot 3[f(x)]^2 \cdot f'(x)=0$

Now solve for $f'(x)$ and plug in the given information.